# setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA

Tags: cuda

Installing the CUDA toolkit results in the following instructions being printed to the console.

> Please make sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> for 64-bit Linux distributions includes /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
>
> OR
>
> for 64-bit Linux distributions add /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 and /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
> to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig as root

The following code in `/etc/profile` had no effect.

```
if [ -z "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then    
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
else
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That is, rebooting and issuing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` showed the variable was not defined.

To try the alternative suggestion, I added the two lines to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` so my file looks like this

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf 
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
```

Then I issued:

`sudo ldconfig`

then

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Still the environment variable was not set.  How do I comply with the CUDA installation instructions shown above?

Comment: ldconfig doesn't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it includes libraries in a different way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the following in `.bashrc`.

```
if [ -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
else
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I think the preferred method is to create a .conf file.  I described this in my answer below.

Answer (score 20):

Add a file with the `.conf` extension to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`  that contains the paths to the libraries and then run ldconfig.  Be sure to set the permissions and ownership of the file to match the other files in the directory.

This is a system wide solution as opposed to the user specific solution of modifying .bashrc.

On my system I made `nvidia.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.  The file contains the lines:

```
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib
```

If you create the file as `sudo` then your permissions should be good to go, but my `nvidia.conf` is owner/group root and rw-r--r-- (or 644).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. ldconfig doesn't set the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: My understanding is that it fixes the problem in such a way that you do not need to set the path variable. So if "doesn't work" means the variable isn't set, then sure. If "doesn't work" means CUDA isn't working, then more information on your problem is needed as this enabled (and continues to enable) CUDA development on my setup.

Comment: I'm sure it works for some things, the program I was trying to compile wants to use the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which is probably not best practise, it means I need to set it!

Comment: in my case on Ubuntu 22.04 with cuda 12.1 this worked just replace 5.0 with 12.1