# Ubuntu 16.04 install cuda 6.5

Tags: cuda

I cant install cuda 6.5 in ubuntu 16.04

I used the deb from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-65
Its supposed to add a PPA. It did it once then I removed it after the sudo update complained about not being able to read from the PPA.

Then I tried to add the PPA using the deb again and now the PPA is not added. Is there another way of installing cuda toolkit 6.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I found a way!

## install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ build-essential automake linux-headers-$(uname -r) git gawk libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev xorg libc++-dev libgmp-dev python-dev
```

## Install the nvidia display driver

Get the appropriate driver download [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). Let's say the latest version is `352.41`.

```
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.41.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.41.run --accept-license --no-questions --disable-nouveau --no-install-compat32-libs
rm NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.41.run
sudo echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"' >> /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration  # flags enable OC and fan controls.
```

## install cuda

```
cd && wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
rm cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-6-5 # skip reading the entire agreement by pressing ctrl+c
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER
echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

## Reboot and test everything works

```
sudo reboot
```

Make the deviceQuery sample. This is used to verify cuda works
    cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery && sudo make

If you see all of your cards listed, and the last line says "Result = PASS" you're good to go.
    /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery

[Source](https://steemit.com/monero/@mobidick/how-to-mine-monero-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-ccminer-cryptonight)

---

Original answer:

I just spent a few hours trying to figure this out myself. I finally got it installed, but now I constantly get variations of this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/cuda_runtime.h:59:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/host_config.h:82:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc 4.9 and up are not supported!
```

I've Google'd around and there are hacks to kinda make it work a little, but eventually you run into a brick wall. I'm giving up and getting a video card that supports the latest CUDA. Simply put, Nvidia just doesn't support Ubuntu 16.04+ with CUDA 6.5 >:C

If you won't heed my warning and are determined to install CUDA 6.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, here are some of the references I used:

[1] https://askubuntu.com/a/149224/422690
[2] https://askubuntu.com/a/278840/422690
[3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216137/4212158
[4] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/WaNmWZqMnzw

Answer (score -1):

Here is the easy way to install the Nvidia CUDA toolkit and proprietary driver that matches your Ubuntu 16.04 system:

1. Open synaptic (or maybe another package manager) and go to `Settings -> Repositories`. On the `Additional Drivers` tab install the proprietary Nvidia driver. It may offer you more than one or you may need to run an apt update/synaptic reload after adding the **restricted** software repository.
2. Also in synaptic install the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package. This **has** to be compatible with the driver that you are using. By installing both from the Ubuntu repositories ensures they are compatible.
3. You may need to set an environment path in your `.bashrc` to point to `/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/`. The libraries are installed in `/usr/lib/nvidia-*` where * is the driver version number.
4. Run `nvidia-smi` to check everything worked.

This is more-or-less the same answer as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/963629/476593).