# I have to add add PATH to /etc/environment but it breaks my machine - why?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, cuda, tensorflow

I'm trying to work with tensorflow on Ubuntu 18.04 using [Deep Learning AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/ubuntu18-04.html) from Amazon which has all CUDA verions installed. However, it's not so easy to make tensorflow 1.X work with GPU because some $PATH problems. When no action is taken, this run time error happens while using TF 1.X:

```
2020-03-25 16:31:58.162200: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**But it works correctly for TF 2.X**

So after reading some posts [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428415/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file) this or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159194/tensorflow-libcudart-so-7-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di), i decided to add this commands to 1) `~/.bashrc` and later to 2) `~/.profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH"
```

but with no effect (I did restart machine or use `source ~/.bashrc` command).

However, if I add these variables to `/etc/environment` then tensorflow finds these variables and works perfectly! Problem is, that it completely breaks machine as, i assume, it overrides all other `$PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables.
My theory is, that because `/etc/environment` has the highest priority the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64` is exactly what TF 1.X requires.

**Question**:

How do I add this variable correctly, so TF 1.X finds it's CUDA-10.0 files and TF 2.X finds its higher CUDA versions?

Comment: `/etc/environment` is not a script file, and thus unable to expand variables. So it ought to work if you state all the directories explicitly and drop the variables. (And you can drop the "export" command, too. It serves no purpose in `/etc/environment`.)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question lies here: [setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210884/setting-ld-library-path-for-cuda?rq=1) and its [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/278840/1061995) but do not forget to do `sudo ldconfig`